# Is there a way to set the src attribute of img or audio/video from binary content

Tags: javascript, src

so imagine I perform an ajax request that sends a name of a image file to my PHP server and the server is NOT ALLOWED to send a link to the file ... instead it will send the contents of the file through PHP's readfile(); function.
when this data is returned, how should JavaScript set an img element's src attribute e.g

```
myXMLHttpRequest.onload=function(){
  imgElement.src= /*some way to work with myXMLHttpResponse.reponseText*/;
}
```

OK, the main point here is to set the src from a string where that string is binary content of an image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and regularly done.

Simply use the URL of your PHP script.  Don't bother with XHR.

```
<img src="your-image-script.php" />
```

Comment: is there another way? because the php script returns data depending on the data the ajax request posted to it... and i cannot send that data by GET request in the link...

Comment: If you're unable to send the request data in the querystring, there is another way.  It's easiest if you use the Fetch API.  Something like, `const res = await fetch('script.php', { method: 'POST', body: yourData });`, to make the HTTP request.  Then, `img.src = URL.createObjectURL(await res.blob());`.

Comment: @elwanga Actually, MDN has example source code that does exactly this:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob